Is it possible to use a smaller width tube to fit a significantly larger width tire?
Would a 20"x1.75"x2.25"width tube possibly work on my 20x4.0" fat tire E-Bike???
I was hoping that I could temporarily use this tube just to get up to the store to buy a 20x4.0" tube thinking it could work temporarily. Please inform me if anyone has tried this method or not and if it's a good idea or not.
Thanks
Philly

It may, but it may not. That may be too big of an ask, but you could always try it.  Don’t over-do it. What’s the worst that can happen?

It can work, as the tubes will expand pretty significantly.  It is not a good idea for long term use, as it will stretch the rubber pretty thin, which makes it more susceptible to valve tear outs and punctures.
The small diameter of the tube compared to the volume of the tire can make it difficult to get enough pressure to seat the tire on the rim, but it is possible, if not easy.
For an EMERGENCY, this is a valid option.

I've used narrower tubes, when I upsized a tyre, forgot to change the spare tube on the bike, and then had a flat.
Installing an 18-25mm tube in a 28mm tyre worked fine, but it ruptured a couple of days later.
In an emergency, you can "overinflate" a tube by 20-25% and still ride it though long-term durability is questionable.
Curiously, cheaper tubes will overstretch more than good tubes because they tend to be thicker butyl rubber.
Don't be fooled thinking that just because you can inflate a tube in free-air (ie outside of a tyre) and have it expand to 4 inches/100mm in diameter, that you could ride on this tube.   In free air, the pressure inside the tube is under 5 PSI.  By the time it has riding-pressures inside and is constrained inside the tyre, there's a lot more energy and any weakness in the tube will be its failure point.

If it was a real emergency, you might get away with inflating and capping one  or two of your smaller tubes, stuffing them inside the tyre, and then installing an additional tube like normal.  This would give the volume but the extra valves inside the tyre will likely cause problems quickly.
This would also risk ruining your tyre, and they're a lot more expensive than a tube.
Your best option is to just walk or bus to the store.  Also buy two tubes.   One for installing and one to carry as an on-bike spare.
